# Gitlab CI variable issue extracting subgroup path for Pages

Tags: sed, devops, gitlab-ci

I am trying to extract the Gitlab Pages path for my subgroup project.

The `CI_PAGES_URL` variable is `https://mygroup.gitlab.io/subgroup/project/`. I used the following script to extract the path:

```sh
echo $CI_PAGES_URL | sed -E 's#^(http|https)://([[:alnum:]\.\-\_]+)(/.+)$#\3#g'
```

In my local environment, everything seems fine:

```sh
> export CI_PAGES_URL=https://mygroup.gitlab.io/subgroup/project/
> echo $CI_PAGES_URL | sed -E 's#^(http|https)://([[:alnum:]\.\-\_]+)(/.+)$#\3#g'

/subgroup/project/
```

But in the Gitlab CI environment, things didn't go as expected:

```sh
> echo $CI_PAGES_URL | sed -E 's#^(http|https)://([[:alnum:]\.\-\_]+)(/.+)$#\3#g'

/project/
```

Naturally, I've checked other submatches:

```sh
> echo $CI_PAGES_URL | sed -E 's#^(http|https)://([[:alnum:]\.\-\_]+)(/.+)$#\1#g'

https

> echo $CI_PAGES_URL | sed -E 's#^(http|https)://([[:alnum:]\.\-\_]+)(/.+)$#\2#g'

mygroup.gitlab.io/subgroup

> echo $CI_PAGES_URL | sed -E 's#^(http|https)://([[:alnum:]\.\-\_]+)(/.+)$#\3#g'

/project/
```

I've checked the `sed` version. Both the CI and my local environment are using `GNU sed 4.4`.

What is going on?

Comment: You can't escape chars in bracket expressions since `/` is treated as  a regular slash. `-` as a literal `-` must be at the start/end. Try `sed -E 's#^(https?)://([[:alnum:]._-]+)(/.+)#\3#g'` or even `sed -E 's#^https?://[[:alnum:]._-]+(/.+)#\1#g'`

Comment: Thanks. I would try. But if that were the problem, why does the expression work on my local environment.

Comment: try quoting your variables. `echo "$CI_PAGES_URL"`

Comment: Yes, if your `CI_PAGES_URL` variable contains spaces you must quote it.

Comment: I'll try quoting the variable. But there should not be any space in the variable at all.

Comment: Tried both method. The result is still the same. Basically things work on my local environment perfectly. But they don't work in the CI environment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out this fixed my problem. And I still have no idea why there is a difference between my local environment and the CI. But there you have it:

```sh
echo "$CI_PAGES_URL" | sed -E 's#^(http|https)://([[:alnum:]\.-\_]+?)(/.+)$#\3#g'
```

There are 2 changes:

- Quoted the variable `$CI_PAGES_URL`.
- Added the lazy qualifier `?` to the domain name match (`\2`).

Comment: `+?` does not make sense since POSIX ERE does not support non-greedy quantifiers

Comment: None of this make sense to me. The same script should works the same in my environment as in the CI environment. But this is what works for me in the CI environment. Just quoting the variable doesn't work.